# How to edit this preg_replace to replace this sequence?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to remove the _7935918 from the tag below that it is in an html file using

```
$str = preg_replace('/.*?(.*?)(_[0-9]{7})/', '$1', $html);

<span id="cld_tle_7935918" class="p_to" id="">
```

without luck.
so my point is to leave it as `<span id="cld_tle" class="p_to" id="">`

Am I missing something?

Comment: does it have to be preg only solution?

Comment: @Andrew no not necessarily

Comment: `$html` is the `cld_tle_7935918` ?? or the whole tag??

Comment: @Andrew `$html` is a `file_get_contents` of a webpage. this tag (and many others) are in the html code. however i want to remove the `_.......` of every tag

Comment: sorry im not an expert on `preg_replace`, but could you try this pattern ?? `'/(cld_tle)(_[0-9]{7})/'`

Comment: @Andrew hey that worked. However I have to add it for every different tag. Is there any way that gets only the `_....` ?

Comment: It depends, are there always only numbers? Something like `(_\d+)$` would work. It says, search for an underscore with infinite (but min 1) numbers at the end of the string ($) and capture it in a  group. This can be replaced/deleted via `preg_replace()`.

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos that's out of my knowledge, I will let others handle this professionally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes little sense to have `.*(.*?)`: what would you expect to capture with that capture group?

Instead you could explicitly require that you want to make replacements in quoted strings only. Also I think it is reasonable to expect that the number of digits might not always be exactly 7. Would it be OK to require at least 2 digits, but also replace any greater number of digits?

I would suggest this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/"([\w_]*?)_[0-9]{2,}"/', '"$1"', $html);
```

You can increase the `{2,}` to whatever you think is best.